# AJAX used for updating page failing

Tags: php, ajax

I am using the following ajax to update information on a page and then resubmit the page into the database. The script is failing each time stopping at the Error parameter. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

AJAX -

```
function bookingdetails() {
    var date = <?php the_time('Y-m-d');?>;
    var airport = $('#FLTairport').val();
    var number = $('#FLTnumber').val();
    var time = $('#FLTtime').val();

    var dataString = 'date=' + date + '&airport=' + airport + '&number=' + number + '&time=' + time;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo $thisposturl;?>?update',
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#airloader').html('<img id="BKloader" src="http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-images/structure/icons/blockloader.gif" alt="" width="40" height="30"/>');
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#airloader').html('Failed to update booking, try again');
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#date').val(data.date);
            $('#FLTnumber').val(data.FLTnumber);
            $('#airloader').val(data.FLTnumber);
            $('#FLTairport').val(data.FLTairport);
            $('#FLTdate').val(data.FLTdate);
            $('#FLTtime').val(data.FLTtime);
        }


    });
}
```

PHP -

```
<?php

function __update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value = '' )
{
    if ( empty( $value ) OR ! $value )
    {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name );
    }
    elseif ( ! get_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name ) )
    {
        add_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value );
    }
    else
    {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, $value );
    }
}

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $my_post = array(
        'ID' => get_the_ID(),
        'post_date' => $_POST['date'],
        );
    $the_post_id = wp_update_post( $my_post );

    __update_post_meta( $the_post_id, 'FLTairport', $_POST['airport'] );
    __update_post_meta( $the_post_id, 'FLTnumber', $_POST['number'] );
    __update_post_meta( $the_post_id, 'FLTtime', $_POST['time'] );
}

$FLTdate = get_the_time('d/m/Y');
$date = get_the_time('Y-m-d');
$FLTairport = $_POST['airport'];
$FLTnumber = $_POST['number'];
$FLTtime = $_POST['time'];

echo json_encode( array('FLTdate'=>$FLTdate, 'date'=>$date, 'FLTairport'=>$FLTairport, 'FLTnumber'=>$FLTnumber, 'FLTtime'=>$FLTtime));
?>
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: Why are you tagging `?update` to the end of the url?

Comment: That is the location of the PHP file as determined by another script that reference the page with an include function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) shows 3 arguments that can be used in your error callback, which could be very useful in debugging your error.

From the docs

[image]

so with that in mind, try changing your error callback like so...

```
error: function(xhr,ts,et) {
    $('#airloader').html('Failed to update booking.');
    $('#airloader').append('Error Text - '+ts);
},
```

and you should see the specific error, which should put you down the right path to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see what your php script is sending? I would recommend using firebug in firefox to see exactly what is coming back to be consumed by your javascript. I don't see where it is outputting a success parameter for your json.